# Proxies, type level symbols, and JSON

Tags: haskell, types, proxy, vinyl

I'm trying to add automagical json parsing to Data.Vinyl

Here is an instance for FromJSON for records with exactly one element.

It almost works, but I can't satisfy the KnownSymbol constraint, it seems to auto generate a new type variable on me.

```
instance (KnownSymbol sym, FromJSON a) => FromJSON (PlainRec '[ sym ::: a ]) where
    parseJSON (Object v) = (field =:) <$> (v .: json_name)
        where field = Field :: (sym ::: a)
              json_name = T.pack $ show field
```

The error is

```
Could not deduce (KnownSymbol sym0) arising from a use of ‛show’
from the context (KnownSymbol sym, FromJSON a)
```

More context http://lpaste.net/101005

If I replace all instances of `sym` with `"name"`, it works, and runs and it is wonderful.  Now, I could use template Haskell to generate all the instances ahead of time, since I have a closed list of field names that I'll actually use, but that seems like such a shame.  I know next to nothing about Data.Proxy, having just seen in used to define the show instance for the records of Data.Proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to enable `ScopedTypeVariables`.